# adding layout within another layout error

Tags: android, android-layout

when i'm trying to add a layout within layout it caught the exception msg like this

```
    You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID @layout/item_composer_header is not valid.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

and my 1st layout is (item_composer_header.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:id="@+id/list_section_header"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:background="@drawable/list_header_bg"  
   android:padding="4dp"  
   android:paddingLeft="10dp"  
   android:shadowColor="#000"  
   android:shadowDx="1"  
   android:shadowDy="1"  
   android:shadowRadius="1"  
   android:text="Header"  
   android:textColor="#FFF"  
   android:textSize="16sp"  
   android:textStyle="bold"  
   android:typeface="serif" />
```

and embed that layout into this 2nd layout(item_composer.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--     <include  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     layout="@layout/item_composer_header" />   -->

     <include android:id="@+id/header_layer"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         layout="@layout/item_composer_header"/>

   <LinearLayout  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"  
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"  
     android:background="@drawable/custom_list_item_bg"  
     android:orientation="vertical"  
     android:paddingBottom="3dp"  
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"  
     android:paddingRight="10dp"  
     android:paddingTop="3dp" >  

     <TextView  
       android:id="@+id/list_section_title1"  
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:text="Full Name"  
       android:textColor="#000000"  
       android:textStyle="bold" />  
     <TextView  
       android:id="@+id/list_section_title2"  
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
       android:text="1500-1600"  
       android:textColor="#000000" />  
   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

How can i come out of this exception?

Comment: Try cleaning your project first and then build and run it

Comment: so what about to check exception at `Window > Show View > Error Log`

Answer (score 0):

Check this to merge different layouts

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

SourceCode: http://progx.org/users/Gfx/android/MergeLayout.zip